# simple Dynamic 2d Array Problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, 2d

Help With a JS double array. the arrays should be set so that the first is a x and the second is a y but so that it is creating a table that has default values of 0000 for each coordinate value and so that i can set values of each coorinate. also i want to be able to echo the array out in the form of a table like

```
___________________________________
|valueof 0,0| valueof 1,0|
|Valueof 0,1| valueof 1,1|
```

and so on using the width and height

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var height=4;
var width=3;
var map = new Array(height);
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) 
    {
        map[i] = new Array(width);
    }

for (var i = 0; i < y; i++) 
{
   for(var j = 0; j < x; i++)
    {
       map[i][j] = "0000";
    }
}
map[1][1]= "0064";
document.write(map[0][0]); // should output 0000
document.write(map[1][1]); // should output 0064
document.write(map[3][4]); // should output 0000
</script>
```

This is soposed to echo the values in the array just those coorinates.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var height=4;
var width=3;
var map = [];
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) 
{
    map[i] = [];
}

for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) 
{
   for(var j = 0; j < width; i++)
     {
        map[i][j] = "0000";
     }
}
map[1][1]= "0064";
document.write(map[0][0]); // should output 0000
document.write(map[1][1]); // should output 0064
document.write(map[3][4]); // should output 0000
</script>
```

i then implemented this a bit farther and got this.

http://lastchaos.bloodkittens.com:34260/Resources/DevApps/fuck.php